# Monero deposit did not arrive on binance

Tags: binance

I have made a deposit of XMR at 16:29:50 CET on 2018-05-02 (Now almost 16 hours ago). I am using Monero GUI v0.11.1.0. The transaction id is e793d31e00250540da8a1edab7a2aab6f063767e1c604c6634c5b9e9f2c1afad. I have used the correct payment id and deposit adress but the XMR's are still not on my Binance account. The balance on my wallet is back to 0 and all transactions are confirmed. It seems I have done everything correct but my XMR's seem to be lost. Could you please hep me?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is, download the newest version of the [Monero Client GUI](https://getmonero.org/downloads) and import your wallet there. Make sure to user version 0.12.

Then sync the blockchain and let's see if you still have that issue.

I think you will actually see that you still have your Moneros in your wallet and that the transaction didn't work out.